# Cannot make virtual fields work in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have exhausted everything I can find here and elsewhere. It appears others are having success but nothing I do will allow me to see any virtual fields. I have tried both as fields and as getterMethods to no avail. I have made sure latest Sequelize version is installed in my project.

Here is the object definition:

```
var Orderitem = sequelize.define("Orderitem", {
    description: { type: DataTypes.STRING(80), allowNull: false },
    quantity: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2), allowNull: false, defaultValue: 0},
    unitWeight: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2), allowNull: false, defaultValue: 0},
    price: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2), allowNull: false, defaultValue: 0},

    totalPrice: { 
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL(DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2), ['price', 'quantity']),
      get() {
        //return this.getDataValue('unitWeight') * this.getDataValue('quantity');
        return 195.99;
      }
    }, 
    totalWeight: { 
      type:  DataTypes.VIRTUAL(DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2), ['unitWeight', 'quantity']),
      get() {
        //return this.getDataValue('unitWeight') * this.getDataValue('quantity');
        return 45;
      }
    },
  }, {
/*
    getterMethods: {
      testFoo: function () {
          return 'Foo';
      },
      totalPrice: function () { 
        return  this.getDataValue('price') * this.getDataValue('quantity');
      },
      totalWeight: function() {
        return this.getDataValue('unitWeight') * this.getDataValue('quantity');
      }
    },
*/
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Orderitem.belongsTo(models.Order, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    }
}
```

As quoted, it is trying to use attribute definitions with VIRTUAL type. I have also tried with *just* virtual, no additional type or dependencies. For testing I've also hardcoded sample return values.

The alternative of using getterMethods (commented out here) fares no better.

According to everything I can find, I should be able to perform a find (findOne, findAll, etc) and these should be returned as fields along with all the others. The first 4 fields return expected values from the database. The virtual fields are nowhere to be found. Using either method above, what am I doing wrong?

Retrieval code is:

```
OrderController.items = function (orderId, callback) {
    models.Orderitem.findAll({
        //attributes: Object.keys(models.Orderitem.attributes).concat([ 'totalPrice','totalWeight']),
        where: {orderId: orderId}, raw: true
    }).then(function(orderitems) {
        callback(null, orderitems)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        callback(error, null)
    });
 };
```

There is no errors, the items are retrieved as expected, everything works perfectly *except the virtual fields. They are simply not there to be found. requesting raw or full objects makes no difference.

Comment: Seems to work for me, can you paste also your retrieve code?

Comment: Added retrieval code to original post - seems to be no way to format it nicely in a comment.

Comment: Digging through the entire returned objects (with raw turned off) I find reference to my virtual fields at:

    orderlines[0].__proto__

Under that the attributes property is an array of names that includes my virtual fields, and there is a field for every attribute - all are undefined *except* the ones for my virtual fields which have the values I hardcoded above - 199.95 and 45 respectively.

With raw set true, this does not come through. Testing more I also see these will remain undefined if made to be the product of two other fields as they need to be.

Comment: This is because your instance's data is not supposed to be accessed this way. You can safely do `orderitems[0].toJSON()` which will bring the same result as the raw result, but this time with virtuals included :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The virtual works the way it was defined.

The problem is the way you retrieve your results. By using `raw` option in your query, Sequelize assumes that you don't want to create a DAO, so it will not evaluate the virtuals and will not create an Instance itself.

```
OrderController.items = function (orderId, callback) {
    models.Orderitem.findAll({    
        where: {orderId: orderId} // commenting out `raw: true`
    }).then(function(orderitems) {   
        if ( orderitems.length > 0 ) { 
            console.log(orderitems[0].totalPrice);
        };
        callback(null, orderitems)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        callback(error, null)
    });
 };
```

You can read more about `raw` option in the [Sequelize Documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#querysql-options-promise).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The docs for the raw option say nothing about not allowing virtual fields to work so I'm not sure how one is supposed to know that.

So to get the virtual attributes I *cannot* use raw and I *must* convert to JSON?? Seems both, especially not being able to use raw, is potentially going to hurt performance.

Comment: Performance will be hurt. Yes, you are right. Then you can not use virtuals at all and just manage to enrich your `raw` object with whichever values you want. The `raw` option will not instantiate your result, so it will not consider not only virtuals, but types, etc. You will basically bypass all the logic inside your ORM, which is fast - yes, but then why do you need an ORM in first place.

Comment: First: it is now working. Thank you.

The application is being rendered server side, objects are not being sent to or manipulated on the client side. So a full object is not needed for that purpose. On the server side, raw is really not a problem so needing it to get the virtual tables and other good things is not actually an issue. However, having to convert to JSON, then parse it back into objects so it can be rendered is truly a waste of cycles.
<cont'd>

Comment: Fortunately I discovered instance.get(). It resolves virtual/getterMethods, etc. Should be faster then going to JSON and I don't have to parse it back. So I'm happy again. :)

Comment: @WayneNiddery is there a way to use virtual cols with `{raw: true}` ?

Comment: @WayneNiddery no. People keep overusing `raw` b/c they don't know how to get the fields they want. Instead of querying with `raw: true`, just use the `.get()` method from your response. e.g. `User.findOne().then(user => user.get()...`

Comment: @WayneNiddery @drinchev hi guys, may the more fastest solution to get rendered virtual fields is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(modelInstance)`

Answer (score 3):

After performing the find operation (findOne, findAll, etc), you have to access those `virtual fields` explicitly.

Ex.

```
await models.Orderitem.findAll({
  where: { orderId: orderId },
}).then((orderitems) =>
  orderitems.map((orderitem) => {
    console.log('orderitem:', orderitem);
    console.log('totalPrice (virtual field): ', orderitem.totalPrice);
  })
);
```

Look closely that `console.log('orderitem:', orderitem)` does not print `totalPrice`, but `totalPrice` is sitting here, returning its value seen in `console.log('totalPrice (virtual field): ', orderitem.totalPrice)`.

It's a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) value you have to access that value and when you access it Javascript generates value in runtime.